# running out of memory plotting with Google Charts and very sparse data

Tags: google-visualization

We have very sparse data that we are attempting to plot with Google Charts. There are 16 different vectors and each has about 12,000 points. The points are times. All of the times are different. My reading of the API is that I need to create a row where each element corresponds to a different vector. So that's a set of 192,000, where the first element in each row is the time and all of the other elements are null except for the one that has data there, for a total of 3,072,000 elements. When we give this to Google Charts, the browser dies.

The problem with using `arrayToDataTable` is that our array is *sparse*. Likewise, `arrayToDataTable` doesn't work.

My question: is there a more efficient way to do this? Can I plot each data value independently, rather than all at the same time?

Comment: how is the data loaded? are you building one big array, then using `arrayToDataTable`? if you can build json on the server, using [this example format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), you can create the data table directly from json, and it is the fastest way. -- for your time values, what data table column type is used, [`'datetime'`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#datetimes-using-the-date-constructor) or [`'timeofday'`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#working-with-timeofday)?

Comment: it is possible to plot each value independently, but the chart must be re-drawn after each change to the data table.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the answer to this question is to do server-side data reduction in the form of binning. The individual rows each have their own timestamp, but because we are displaying this in a graph with a width of at most 2000 pixel, it makes sense to bin on the server into 2000 individual rows, each one with 16 columns. Then the total array is 32,000 elements, which appears well within the limits of the browser.